# Why is my css grid not working in Chrome (works in all other browsers)

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-grid

I've setup a css grid with 3 columns to display our portfolio. I found a working code for Firefox and Internet Explorer and Safari. However on Chrome it doesn't show my grid at all, all the pictures are below each other. See the website: http://www.ddw-sanitair.be

Additionally it does not accept the 'display: none' class on some of the pictures, hence the double/triple images ...

Any suggestions?

I tried to add grid-auto-rows: 270px; as suggested in another thread.
I tried adding grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr); as suggested in another thread.

But this didn't change anything in Chrome ...

```
.portfolio-group {
    position: relative;
    display:grid;
    align-items: start;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(240px, 1fr));
    grid-auto-rows: 270px;
```

Expected result = a nice reactive grid with 3 columns and 3 rows (in browser view).

Comment: not posible .. if you want you add media

Comment: I just saw this question and I see that your site is working correctly. Might I ask what you did to fix it?

Comment: I honestly don't remember. Feel free to check the source code though ;-)

Answer (score -1):

i hope you will get the ans from this site: `https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2014/06/27/css-grid-layout-getting-to-grips-with-the-chrome-implementation/